# ai aggregate association rules

Tags: artificial-intelligence, associations, aggregate, rules

If I extract certain association rules from a sample itemset consisting of let's say:

a, b -> c
c, d -> e
a, c -> d
b, c -> c

Is there a way to combine the found rules into one formula depending on a fixed item count number were all rules are aggregated to get the most likely combination of all association rules combined?

Let's say the fixed item number is four and the above association rules have to be mixed to get the most likely combination. How would I do that? Are there algorithms or programmes for this?

Answer (score 0):

Each association rule has a confidence and support.

For example  A --> BC   support : 50 %  confidence : 50%.

If you combine several association rules, then how you would calculate the support and confidence of the resulting rule ?  That would be a problem.

Actually, you could look at CBA: Classification by Associations.  This project use association rules to perform classification. Instead of trying to combine association rules, it uses some heuristics to select the rule that is the most appropriate for classifying a new instance.  To choose the best rule, it considers the support, the confidence and the size of the left par of the rule.  There is other similar works.

But I have not seen any work trying to combine association rules... maybe if you search "association rule clustering" in Google you could find something related to your idea.

By the way, besides confidence and support, some people use other interestingness measures like the lift, J-Measure, etc.